# How to access iotHiddenMenu

Tags: system-apps

How do I access the iotHiddenMenu on Samsung galaxy?
The dial code (* #21*#) doesn't work. For that matter no dial code seems to work on my device...

Comment: Try [this](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.vndnguyen.phoneinfo.plus) it *may* showup

Comment: What's this? Is there no way to access without a 3rd party app?

Comment: I used it long way back with Note 2. I haven't used a Samsung phone since then, so I can't suggest